# fetchAll isn't returning correct information

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Where have I gone wrong with this code? I thought the print_r($stmt); would return u_id from the users table however it is just returning the prepared statement.

```
if(isset($_GET['email']) && isset($_GET['token'])) {
  global $pdo;

  $email = $_GET['email'];
  $token = $_GET['token'];

  $sql = ("SELECT u_id FROM users WHERE
    email = ? AND
    token = ? AND
    token<>'' AND
    tokenExpire > NOW()
    ");
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute([$email, $token]);
  $stmt->fetchAll();
  print_r($stmt);
```

Thanks

Comment: You really need to read the documentation!

Comment: What documentation is that? Send me a link if you can please.

Comment: `fetchAll` return an array. Read the docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behaviour. The `fetchAll` method returns an array of results; but you haven't assigned it to a variable and so that line of code does nothing good for you.

However, if you were to do:

```
print_r($stmt->fetchAll());
```

Then you would have the result printed to screen; if you wanted to use the result afterwards, then you need to assign the returned value to a variable:

```
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();

print_r($result);
```

This assigns the result to a variable and then prints out the full set of results.